# Obtain feature names from model when training data is not available

Tags: scikit-learn

Is it possible to obtain the feature names expected by a model if we don't have the training data available?

I want to ensure that I am giving the model the data with features in the correct/expected order. This is in production so I don't have the training data loaded, and thus can't simply get the names and order from `X_train.columns`.

Currently I have 2 hacky ways to do it, but I would prefer a more sensible approach:

1. Catch the `feature_names mismatch` error message which tells me the order it expects. (Problem: I am basically running headfirst into an error and letting the error message tell me what to do.)
2. Store the feature names in a list as an environment variable and use this as a reference to make sure the features are in the correct order before feeding it to the model for prediction. (Problem: this requires manually maintaining that environment variable every time the dataset/model changes and is thus prone to error.)

Note: I am storing/loading the model with `joblib` on Python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can follow the source code that raises this feature names mismatch error, it will eventually test the value against some field that it should be, and then you are able to access it directly, as perhaps `model._feature_names` but probably something nested a bit deeper.

Comment: Great suggestion @Gijs! Indeed, the underlying model has a `feature_names` attribute. It's an XGBoost model, so I have to access it through the `Booster` class like this: `clf._Booster.feature_names` where `clf` was loaded from a pickle through joblib. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah good! I was a bit lazy in my explanation but I'm glad it helped.

Comment: No worries, I got the gist!